# Adding span from JS

Tags: javascript, dom

Why is it that my span is only applying to the first letter being added and stops the buttons functioning after the first one. However if I remove the add spam labels it works fine without spans.`

```
 var letterContainer = document.querySelector(".letter-container");

 document.querySelector(".vow").addEventListener("click", pickFrom(letters));

 function pickFrom(letters) {

   // if the length of the letter container is less than 8
   if (letterContainer.innerHTML.length < 8) {

     //add letters to the letter container
     letterContainer.innerHTML += "<span>"+ rando(letters)+"</span>";

   }
```

[image]

Comment: what do you expect from the condition after 1st run: if (letterContainer.innerHTML.length < 8)

Comment: A random vowel or consonant is chosen and added to the a letter container. I just want to add a box shape/border around each letter as if it's on a card.

Comment: do you want the letter to be chosen only once? if not then remove the condition: if (letterContainer.innerHTML.length < 8) {

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening. As you have not posted full code like what is `letters` in `pickFrom(letters)`? what is `rando(letters)`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cpog19901/v8kpeozr/3/

Comment: I guess the best way to describe it is a library of commands for generating a random number.

Comment: ur fiddle seems to work fine...do u want to append the new letter each time or only once?

Comment: oh i see ur problem now...letterContainer.innerHTML.length < 8 must factor in <span></span>...

Comment: yes, so the user can pick up to 8 letters but for some reason it's only adding one letter with the span. if i remove the span tags it adds all 8. how would I go about factoring in? Would I need to add an && logical operator?

Comment: check my answer...

Comment: Only thing about the answer below is that it puts a span around the whole string of letters and not each individual letter. Sorry I probably should have mentioned that before

Comment: check again....

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var letterContainer = document.querySelector(".letter-container");
let currentLetters = [];
function pickFrom(letters) {

  //or if want to use your original condition without introducing state
  // letterContainer.innerHTML.length < (13*8+8)
   // if the length of the letter container is less than 8
   if (currentLetters.length < 8) {



     //add letters to the letter container
     currentLetters.push(rando(letters));
     letterContainer.innerHTML = currentLetters.map(item => `<span>${item}</span>`).join("");





   }
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>

<div class = "letter-container">
</div>

<button class ="con letter-btn btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" onclick="pickFrom('BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ');">Consonant</button>
<button class =" vow letter-btn btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" onclick="pickFrom('AEIOU');">Vowel</button>
```